# ? extends TSubject extends Subject - Not type safe, or just Java can't handle it?

Tags: java, generics

When compiling this

```
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static class Subject {
    }

    public static class MySubject extends Subject {
    }

    public static class Step<TSubjectA extends Subject> {
        public void doWork(TSubjectA subject) {
        }
    }

    public static class Worker {
        public static <TSubjectB extends Subject> void doWork(TSubjectB subject, List<Step<? extends TSubjectB>> steps) {
            for (Step<? extends TSubjectB> step : steps) {
                step.doWork(subject);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySubject subject;
        List<Step<? extends Subject>> steps;

        Worker.doWork(subject, steps);
    }
}
```

I get the error

> Test.java:18: doWork(capture#95 of ? extends TSubjectB) in Test.Step cannot be applied to (TSubjectB)

From what I can see, `subject` is of type `TSubjectB`, which extends `Subject`. The type `TSubjectA` is a type which extends `TSubjectB` which extends `Subject`. So I should be able to pass `subject` to `doWork` and it should all be typesafe.

Am I missing something and it is actually not typesafe, or is this just a limitation of Java's generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the type parameters `TSubjectA` and `TSubjectB` are each guaranteed to be some type extending `Subject`, they aren't necessarily the same type - one could be `MySubject` and the other could be `MyOtherSubject`.  This is the reason the current code isn't considered typesafe by the compiler.

If the functionality you require is strictly dependent on the `Subject` base implementation, just remove the type parameters and rely on polymorphism:

```
public static class Step {
    public void doWork(Subject subject) {
       //do Subject stuff
    }
}

public static class Worker {
    public static void doWork(Subject subject, List<Step> steps) {
        for (Step step : steps) {
            step.doWork(subject);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Step> steps = ...;

    //all valid
    Worker.doWork(new Subject(), steps);
    Worker.doWork(new MySubject(), steps);
    Worker.doWork(new MyOtherSubject(), steps);
}
```

If it isn't, that is if the `doWork` implementation is different depending on the subtype of `Subject`, then generics won't help you and you'll need to make some design changes.  Keep in mind that generics in Java aren't dynamic magic, but rather syntactic sugar to aid compile-time type safety. Read up on [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) if you haven't already to understand this limitation.